# Are there any way to use method of class as property in LUA?

Tags: lua

In Python, we can use @property decorator to use the method as property.

```
>>> Class A:
>>>    @property
>>>    def b(self):
>>>        return 1
>>> a = A()
>>> a.b
1
```

Is there any way to do this in Lua? Are there any examples of that?

Comment: Maybe you'd want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578935/lua-getters-and-setters

Comment: Just set `A.b=1` and make `a` inherit from `A`.

Comment: In Lua you'd have to use the `__index` metamethod